# How to remove an array based on value

Tags: arrays

I  have  an  array in a variable if i print that array means the array will look like below :

```
Array
(
[Body] => This is TestDrive
[Attachment] => 
)

Array
(
[Body] => Testing to an Loops

[Attachment] => 
)

(
[Body] => Okay

[Attachment] => 
)
```

I want to remove the first array

```
        `Array(
          [Body] => This is TestDrive
          [Attachment] => 
         )`
```

How to do that ? Please any one help me

Comment: Please specify your programming language. And do you have an array of arrays?

Comment: Am using PHP . Yes i have an array of arrays while printing that array i will get the answer like above